# Force Preprocessor Evaluation While Tokenizing

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming

Is there a way to force the preprocessor to completely evaluate the symbols before tokenizing?

An example of the input and output I want `GFR_SER_##token`, `GFR_SER_INT`.

As an example, I'm trying to do some pre-processor meta-programming using Boost::PP.

For pasting strings, it's fairly easy as you just add a level of indirection like:

```
#define str(s) xstr(s)
#define xstr(s) #s
```

However, this doesn't work for tokenizing, as `#define xtkz(t) ##t` is illegal due to the token syntax at the beginning of the expression.

I've tried using `BOOST_PP_IDENTIFY(s)`, which resolves the input, but unfortunately results in tokenization of *that* Boost call such as `GFR_SER_BOOST_PP_IDENTIFY(s)`. Are there good workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same double-expand technique, but you need to remember that `##` is a binary operator:

```
#define XCONCAT(a,b) a##b
#define CONCAT(a,b) XCONCAT(a,b)

#define token INT
CONCAT(GFR_SER_,token)
```

Running the above through `gcc -E` results in:

```
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 30 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/predefs.h" 1 3 4
# 31 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 2 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"




GFR_SER_INT
```